# JS convert a list of objects into another

Tags: javascript

I want to convert a list of objects into another in JS like

A = [{"id":"a", "name":"b", "email":"c"}, {"id":"c", "name":"d", "email":"c"}] to
B = [{"id":"a", "value":"b"}, {"id":"c", "value":"d"}]

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a simple re-mapping of `id -> id` and `name -> value`.

```js
const
  arr = [{"id":"a", "name":"b", "email":"c"}, {"id":"c", "name":"d", "email":"c"}],
  res = arr.map(({ id, name: value }) => ({ id, value }));

console.log(res);
```

Here is a more-verbose version:

```js
const
  arr = [{"id":"a", "name":"b", "email":"c"}, {"id":"c", "name":"d", "email":"c"}],
  res = arr.map(function (item) {
    return {
      id: item.id,
      value: item.name
    };
  });

console.log(res);
```

Comment: You had to know there was a duplicate for this...

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's array method [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to accomplish this.

Map iterates over each element of the array and returns an array.

```js
const A = [{"id":"a", "name":"b", "email":"c"}, {"id":"c", "name":"d", "email":"c"}];

const res = A.map(item => {
  return {
    id: item.id,
    value: item.name,
  };
});

console.log(res)
```